# How to read "Set-cookie" from response header in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I can not read my cookie from the response header marked with the `Set-Cookie` key in my browser.

I can read and get everything in the response header except for the `Set-Cookie`.

My cookie is in the response header in my browser but I can not get or read it in my React project.

I noticed that it is not possible to get `Set-Cookie` in JavaScript.

I even have an extra tab called `Cookies` in my browser in the Inspect section and on the `Network` tab, in addition to the `Headers`, `Payload` tabs, etc., that contain my cookies.

I want to know how to save my cookie after logging in?

I use `axios` and `Redux`.

Thanks to those who help me!

Comment: Can you show us the code on how you sent your cookies? Are you running your server on localhost or a domain?

Comment: my backend code is `c#` and use identity
I set all three "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "access-control-allow-origin" and "access-control-allow-methods".@caslawter

Comment: I  put my server on IIS. @caslawter